# Detectar si pantalla táctil en windows

Tags: jquery

Como podría detectar si estoy sobre un dispositivo táctil y este es windows?

Quiero mostrar un teclado virtual (Plugin de Jquery) pero lo quiero mostrar solo en dispositivos tactiles windows, no me interesa mostrarlo en android.

He intentado esto, pero el teclado sale también en android.

```
if ("ontouchstart" in window || navigator.msMaxTouchPoints) {
    $('#idUsuario').keyboard({ layout: 'qwerty' }) //Muestro teclado
} else {
    isTouch = false;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para detectar windows SO puedes usar esta función

```
function checkWindows() {
  let platform = window.navigator.platform
  let windowsPlatforms = ['Win32', 'Win64', 'Windows', 'WinCE']

  if (windowsPlatforms.indexOf(platform) !== -1) {
     return true
  }
}

alert(checkWindows());
```

El problema vendría a ser, el touch, según lo que sé podría funcionarte un simple

```
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
  //este evento solo se dispara cuando tocas la pantalla entonces
  if (checkWindows) {
      //despliegas el teclado virtual.
  }
});
```

si lo que te interesa es saber si el dispositivo es android o IOs puedes usar esta función.

```
function isMobile () {
        let userAgent = navigator.userAgent || navigator.vendor || window.opera
        if (/android/i.test(userAgent)) {
        return true
    }

    // iOS detection from: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9039885/177710
    if (/iPad|iPhone|iPod/.test(userAgent) && !window.MSStream) {
        return true
    }

    return false
}


window.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
  //este evento solo se dispara cuando tocas la pantalla entonces
  if (!isMobile) {
      //despliegas el teclado virtual.
  }
});
```

Comment: Simplificando la detección del sistema operativo, sería más óptimo solamente buscar la excepción de Android y iOS; en el caso de detectar estos SO, se mostraría el teclado virtual al resto de los dispositivos táctiles incluyendo monitores utilizados en Linux y Mac.

Comment: Se pueden agregar las nuevas plataformas necesarias, para comprobar si es MacOS o Linux, o android y excluirlas sin, problemas, ya depende del usuario. Ya actualizo mi respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Básciamente puedes hacerlo utilizando *javascript vanilla* mediante los eventos de *touch*:

```
let isTouch = false;
window.addEventListener ('touchstart', () => {
  isTouch = true;
});
```

Es necesario ejecutar un evento táctil para saberlo; no puedes saber si tu monitor soporta eventos táctiles antes de esto.

Para resolver tu problema, lo que te recomiendo es mostrar solamente el teclado cuando hagas "*touch*" en un campo de texto (además, esto sería lo mejor para tu **UX**).

```
document.querySelector ('input').addEventListener ('touchstart', () => {
  displayKeyboard ();
});
```